# Show affiliate program banner in laravel with widgetify

Tags: html, asynchronous, widget, laravel-5.1

I am just trying to show banner of affiliate program in laravel 5.1. But its not showing that banner.As per google search i found widgetify package and implemented it successfully but still unable to view banner with this html and script code.

This is my code to show banner:

```
<div data-WRID="WRID-151136341816463865" data-widgetType="productBanner" data-class="affiliateAdsByFlipkart" height="240px" width="120px"></div>
<script async src="//affiliate.flipkart.com/affiliate/widgets/FKAffiliateWidgets.js"></script>
```

and when i am print it in wordpress its working fine.